# Accessing information between scenes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class in Unity that a list of toggle switches that get turned on and off in a separate scene from the rest of my game. What I'm wanting is to have the user select one button and then have a corresponding action happen in my main game when they go back to that scene. However, I'm having issue sending information between scenes.

At the moment my toggle class looks like this:

```
private bool action1 = false;
public bool Action1
{
    get { return action1;}
}

void OnGUI() 
{
    action1 = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), action1, "test");   
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Main");
    }
}
```

Then in a class held in my Main scene, I have the following code:

```
private ActionClass actionIsOn = new ActionClass();
void Start() 
{
    if(actionIsOn.Action1 == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("action is on");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("nothing happening");
    }
}
```

However, when I test this, nothing happens.

Have I set this up correctly? Is there a better way to pass this information from one scene to another?

Answer (score 7):

**Option #1:**

Use a static class to hold global info that's relevant to multiple scenes.

```
public static class GlobalData
{
       public static bool SomeBooleanFlag;
}
```

This way in your first scene you can set `GlobalData.SomeBooleanFlag` to some value, and in your second scene you can check for it.

**Option #2:**

You can use `Object.DontDestroyOnLoad` to ensure that an object in your scene doesn't get destroyed when a new scene is loading. This way you can aggregate all of the info that you want to pass to the other scene in a single object (or use multiple objects, and keep them all alive), and make sure it stays alive even after the scene has changed.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Additionally you could write data to PlayerPrefs which has the benefit of holding data in between game sessions. But in this case I still think the static variable is still the best option.